# Target class [request] does not exist

Tags: laravel, phpunit

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DMO\SavingsBond\Models\Offer;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class BondOfferCRUDTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_bond_offer_Model_CRUD()
    {
        /*
        //Given we have task in the database
        $task = factory('App\Task')->create();

        //When user visit the tasks page
        $response = $this->get('/tasks');
        
        //He should be able to read the task
        $response->assertSee($task->title);*/

        $bondOffer_Data = Offer::create([
            'organization_id' => '1',
            'status' => 'app',
            'offer_title' => 'Apollos Geofrey',
            'price_per_unit' => '100'
        ]);

        $bondOffer_DB = Offer::find($bondOffer_Data->id);

        $this->assertEquals(
            $bondOffer_Data['offer_title'],
            $bondOffer_DB->offer_title
        );
    }
}
```

I am running a phpunit test, to test a model, the error has kept me stocked. See complete error below:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>
> Target class [request] does not exist.
>
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:879

[image: See error returned in terminal]

Each time i run php artisan test, the error is returned.
Please, I don't know what am I doing wrong, i need an assistance on how to solve this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was resolved, i realized the model was using a Trait containing Organization Constraints which somehow alters the Model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Its a error of request class error, you just need to add this class
**use Illuminate\Http\Request;** inside the controller that you calling while hitting the route.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I am not actually using a controller for this.
i am attempting to test my Model for CRUD directly from the unit test class i created without using controllers.

Comment: @ApollosGeofrey don't do that, you **MUST** use the framework to test that as you are not taking Middlewares and other stuff into account doing those test... the [framework documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#introduction) explains everything very correctly, don't reinvent the wheel nor choose to not use it...